# How to check the tokens generated for different tokenizers in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been using different type of tokenizers for test and demonstration purposes. I need to check how a particular text field is tokenized using different tokenizers and also see the tokens generated.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can install inqusitor plugin and test on it: https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from what @Val have mentioned you can try out the [term vecto](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html)r,if you are intending to study the working of tokenisers.You can try out something like this just for examining the tokenisation happening in a field

```
GET /index-name/type-name/doc-id/_termvector?fields=field-to-be-examined
```

To know more about tokenisers and their operations you can refer this [blog](http://blog.qbox.io/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`_analyze` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) for this purpose.

For instance, using the standard analyzer, you can analyze `this is a test` like this

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&pretty' -d 'this is a test'
```

And this produces the following tokens:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "this",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "is",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "a",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "test",
    "start_offset" : 10,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 4
  } ]
}
```

Of course, you can use any of the [existing analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and you can also specify tokenizers using the `tokenizer` parameter, token filters using the `token_filters`parameter and character filters using the `char_filters` parameter. For instance, analyzing the HTML `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=keyword&token_filters=lowercase&char_filters=html_strip' -d 'THIS is a <b>TEST</b>'` using the standard analyzer, the `keyword` tokenizer, the `lowercase` token filter and the `html_strip` character filter yields this, i.e. a lowercase single token without the HTML markup:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=keyword&token_filters=lowercase&char_filters=html_strip' -d 'THIS is a <b>TEST</b>'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "this is a test",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Note: you can also use the `text` query param instead of submitting the string in the body with `-d`.